Not Producing Expected Results in LINQ Query
I am new to LINQ and am trying to get results of a Win Form ComboBox to populate another ComboBox.  When I click on the intended ComboBox, nothing appears.  Would anyone like to take a look at my code and see where I am going wrong?  Much appreciation in advance.  Note:  graphic shows location type selected as "Hometown."  The box below it should show the actual Hometown, as in San Antonio.
private void LocationComboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastNameTextBox.Text))
    {                
        using PersonsContext dbContext = new PersonsContext();
        List<string?> filteredResults = new List<string?>();

        var tempResults = dbContext.Persons
            .Where(a => EF.Functions.Collate(a.LastName, "NOCASE") == lastNameTextBox.Text)
            .GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(a => a.Name == locationTypeComboBox.Text)
            .Select(a => a.GetValue(a, null)).FirstOrDefault();
        if (tempResults != null) 
        {
           
            filteredResults.Add(tempResults.ToString());
            filteredResults.Sort();
            filteredResults = filteredResults.Distinct().ToList();
            locationComboBox.Items.Clear();
            locationComboBox.Items.AddRange([.. filteredResults]);
            locationComboBox.Items.Remove(String.Empty);
        }                
    }
    else
    {
        // todo:
    }
}


Edited:  Update:  I was able to utilize code example written by @Fildor (Thank you) and the following works:
  private void LocationComboBox_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastNameTextBox.Text))
    {
        var projections = new Dictionary<string, Func<Person, object?>>()
        {
            [nameof(Person.LastName)] = p => p.LastName,
            [nameof(Person.Hometown)] = p => p.Hometown,
            [nameof(Person.County)] = p => p.County,
            [nameof(Person.State)] = p => p.State,
            [nameof(Person.Country)] = p => p.Country
        };
        
        var projection = projections[locationTypeComboBox.Text];
        
        using PersonsContext dbContext = new PersonsContext();
     
        var filteredResults = dbContext.Persons
            .Where(a => EF.Functions.Collate(a.LastName, "NOCASE") == lastNameTextBox.Text)
            .Select(projection)
            .ToList();

        filteredResults.Sort();
        filteredResults = filteredResults.Distinct().ToList();
        locationComboBox.Items.Clear();
        locationComboBox.Items.AddRange([.. filteredResults]);
        locationComboBox.Items.Remove(String.Empty);
    }                
    else
    {
        // todo:
    }
}


Thank you again for your work and help on this!

.GetType() .GetProperties()  what do you think this does? I am pretty sure you don't want it.

I would like to get the "Name" of the Property of the locationTypeComboBox.Text matches the Name of the property of the entity.  As in person.Hometown.

Yes, but GetType() on dbContext.Persons.Where() probably will give you an IQueryable<Person> not a Person, right? dbContext is probably some derivative of DbContext, .Persons a DbSet<Person> and a Where on that gives you an IQueryable<T> where T is Person in this case, if I am not mistaken.

^^ Which means .Where(a => a.Name == locationTypeComboBox.Text) on its property collection will give you an empty set. Always. Because IQueryable has no property "Hometown".

I see.  I will look into this.  Thank you.

Well, it's not going to hurt. I'll try and think of something, that could work for you, though. Will the "person" class be somewhat stable or are you expecting frequent changes to it or are different types planned to be used with this, too? Asking for the degree of freedom. Reflection for me is kind of like a "last resort" if all other attempts have failed.

Thank you very much.  In the meantime, I'll keep learning more about what you wrote.

Also: What version of Entity Framework are we talking about? That might be important, so we know what features we have at our disposal.

.Net 8.0 .  I'm checking on the version of EF.  I thought it was EF 6.  How do I check in Visual Studio 2022?

It's the version of the NuGet that is referenced. You can also check the version of the EF tooling, depends on what you have installed.

I see Entity Framework Core 9.0 in Nuget Package Manager

I'm also using SQLite.

Just re-read your earlier comment.  The Person class is stable and I am using Win Form to save Person(s) to the SQLite database.  I wasn't using Reflection at first, and I had success.  I was just trying another approach to use less code.

I can resort to my earlier code which worked though.  I was trying my hand at LINQ to see if I can optimize my code.

"If it ain't broke don't fix it" :D I totally get it, though. And for these purposes it would be pretty convenient if we could do that, but it doesn't exactly work that way. BUT: You could make a Raw SQL Query, so you can "inject" the Column name you want to project. Of course that's a little tricky, we don't want to open up to sql injection attacks.

You're absolutely right!  Thank you for your expert advise.  I think I will revert to my previous code.  I did successfully use Reflection on a few other Event Handlers and they worked, but they did not pose trying to get the "Name" property.  Thank you again for your help!

https://dotnetfiddle.net/1mDatc something like this should work. If that's of use?

I will take a look.  Thank you!

Works now.  Thank you.
